# Can EXPLAIN provide more than just a Query Plan?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, performance, oracle, informix

It would be useful to also know Disk Reads/Writes, Memory, CPU, etc. statistics for a given SQL statement.

Comment: It depends on your OS and your RDBMS.  Microsoft SQL Server, for example, has *TONS* of performance counters you can use!

Comment: Does SQL-Server's EXPLAIN provide these statistics, or is it external?

Comment: Some are available from T-SQL (e.g. "show plan"), some are available in [SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx), many others are available in Windows [Perfmon](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2005/sql-server-performance-monitor-coutners/)

Comment: I would think that having as many statistics possible within EXPLAIN, exclusively for the SQL statement being executed, would provide the most accurate results?

Comment: Are you asking about a specific RDBMS, or are you asking if there's an ANSI standard?  This question is overly broad.

Comment: Well, do any SQL/RDBMS' offer everything I'm looking for?.. If not, which one offers the most?.. I feel its very important to accurately know what the disk, memory, CPU, etc. are doing besides obtaining just a query plan and a cost estimate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 4 different DBMS in the tags.  Each of them provides abundant extra information about a query via different mechanisms — not usually through EXPLAIN itself, which is the optimizer's way of predicting the cost of a query rather than recording what it does cost.  However, the mechanisms by which this is done are quite different in each DBMS, being well beyond the reach of anything other than de facto standards (and each DBMS is its own de facto standard).

Answer (score 3):

The Oracle Explain tool is a cost estimating tool, not a predictor of resource consumption. You can query the dictionary in Oracle (e.g., the V$SQLAREA view) for actual resource consumption for a given SQL statement.

As an aside, two SQL statements might yield the same execution plan but could be considered different SQL statements by Oracle.

Comment: I feel its a very important analytical tool to know the resource consumption for any SQL statement being executed!.. Perhaps an SQL statement like 'TRACE ON...' could provide this info after the statement has been executed?

Comment: In Oracle SQL*Plus, you can execute SET AUTOTRACE ON for I/O information.

Comment: you can use `gather_plan_statistics` hint (or `statistics_level=all`)
 too